# Replace variables values between two files using VBS

Tags: regex, variables, vbscript, replace

I'm dealing with a script and I won't be able to create it without your help.
This is what I need: I have two .txt files, one contains variables (between two `@`) like these:

```
@PickupFolder@=E:/SonicDataFiles/AR_INT/GPP_VE/IN           
@Db1Url@=jdbc:sonic:sqlserver://CARASETMS:1433;databaseName=CRM
```

The other .txt have variables that need to be completed from the previous file

```
@Db1Url@=
@Db1Pwd@=
```

I need to get every variable in the first file (I guess I have to use regular expression) and replace its value in the second file if the variable exits.

I would really appreciate if anyone has a similar script to get an idea. I'm trying to do it with VBS.

Thanks a lot.

Gerardo.
Buenos Aires, Argentina.

This was my original script:

```
            'ReplaceScript "c:\Variables_INT.txt" "C:\AR_INT.tailoring.properties"

            'DEFINE CONSTANTS
            Const ForReading = 1
            Const ForWriting = 2
            Const ForAppending = 8

            'DEFINE VARIABLES
            strTxtFile = Wscript.Arguments(0)
            strTailoringFile = Wscript.Arguments(1)
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set WshShl = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            Set objFileVariablesTXT = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strTxtFile, ForReading)                      'Variables_INT.txt
            Set objFileTailoring = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strTailoringFile, ForReading)                   'AR_INT.tailoring.properties
            Dim strQuartz, strPickupfFolder, strUrl, strDbPwd, strDbUser, strDbDestTable

            strSearchString = objFileVariablesTXT.ReadAll
            'SEARCH THE FILE FOR THE NEEDED DATA
                vQuartz = InStr(strSearchString, "@QuartzJars@=")
                vPickupFolder = InStr(strSearchString, "@PickupFolder@=")
                vDbUrl = InStr(strSearchString, "@Db1Url@=")
                vDbPwd = InStr(strSearchString, "@Db1Pwd@=")
                vDbUser = InStr(strSearchString, "@Db1User@=")
                vDbDestTable = InStr(strSearchString, "@DestinationTable@=")

            'PARSE OUT THE NEEDED INFO
                If vQuartz <> 0 Then
                    'vQuartz = vQuartz + 13
                    strQuartz = Mid(strSearchString, vQuartz, 304)
                        ' WScript.Echo strQuartz
               End If 
               If vPickupFolder <> 0 Then
                    'vPickupFolder = vPickupFolder + 15
                    strPickupfFolder = Mid(strSearchString, vPickupFolder, 50)
                     '    WScript.Echo strPickupfFolder
               End If 
               If vDbUrl <> 0 Then
                    'vDbUrl = vDbUrl + 9
                    strUrl = Mid(strSearchString, vDbUrl, 65)
                       '  WScript.Echo strUrl
               End If 
               If vDbPwd <> 0 Then
                    'vDbPwd = vDbPwd + 9
                    strDbPwd = Mid(strSearchString, vDbPwd, 17)
                         'WScript.Echo strDbPwd
               End If 
               If vDbUser <> 0 Then
                    'vDbUser = vDbUser + 10
                    strDbUser = Mid(strSearchString, vDbUser, 25)
                         'WScript.Echo strDbUser
               End If 
               If vDbDestTable <> 0 Then
                    'vDbDestTable = vDbDestTable + 19
                    strDbDestTable = Mid(strSearchString, vDbDestTable, 29)
                         'WScript.Echo strDbDestTable
               End If 

            objFileVariablesTXT.Close


            strReplaceString = objFileTailoring.ReadAll


            arrReplacements = Array("@QuartzJars@=Ç" & strQuartz , "@PickupFolder@=Ç" & strPickupfFolder, "@Db1Url@=Ç" & strUrl, "@Db1Pwd@=Ç" & strDbPwd, "@Db1User@=Ç" &strDbUser, "@DestinationTable@=Ç" & strDbDestTable)

            objFileTailoring.Close

            Set objFileTailoring = Nothing

            For Each strReplacement In arrReplacements
                    strReplaceWhat = Split(strReplacement, "Ç")(0)
                    'WScript.Echo strReplaceWhat
                    strReplaceWith = Split(strReplacement, "Ç")(1)
                    'WScript.Echo strReplaceWith
                    strReplaceString = Replace(strReplaceString, strReplaceWhat, strReplaceWith)
            Next
            'wScript.Echo strReplaceString

            Set objFileTailoring = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTailoringFile, 2, true)
            objFileTailoring.Write strReplaceString

            objFileTailoring.Close
```

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois.
Yes I have created a script which works, but my problem was that I need a script to find every variable in a file, I was hardcoding their name to search for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this brute force approach, it works for me...

```
Dim FSO, txs, all, sourceLines, i, targetLines, j, delimiterPosition
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set txs = FSO.OpenTextFile(".\source.txt", 1)
all=txs.ReadAll
txs.Close
sourceLines=Split(all,vbCrLf)
set txs = FSO.OpenTextFile(".\target.txt", 1)
all=txs.ReadAll
txs.Close
targetLines=Split(all,vbCrLf)

for i = 0 to ubound(sourceLines)
    If sourceLines(i)<>"" Then
        delimiterPosition = InStr(2, sourceLines(i), "@")
        sourceVarName = Mid(sourceLines(i), 2, delimiterPosition - 2)
        sourceVarValue = Mid(sourceLines(i), delimiterPosition + 2)

        for j = 0 to ubound(targetLines)
            If targetLines(j)<>"" Then
                delimiterPosition = InStr(2, targetLines(j), "@")
                targetVarName = Mid(targetLines(j), 2, delimiterPosition - 2)
                If targetVarName = sourceVarName Then
                    targetLines(j) = targetLines(j) & sourceVarValue
                End If
            End If
        next
    End If
next

set txs = FSO.OpenTextFile(".\target.txt", 2)
for j = 0 to ubound(targetLines)
    txs.WriteLine targetLines(j)
next
txs.Close
```

Target file is now:

```
@Db1Url@=jdbc:sonic:sqlserver://CARASETMS:1433;databaseName=CRM
@Db1Pwd@=
```

Comment: +1 : meeting the specs is more important than implementation.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks a lot for your help. Sorry that I don't have much experience in vbs and maybe this could be a silly question. I'm getting an error in line 22 "Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid'". Any idea of why could it be?

Comment: Calling `Mid` on e.g. an empty string will do that... Try `MsgBox sourceLines(i)` before line 22 to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I had a comment line (#----- Custom Configuration ------) that was making the script fail.. I removed it and it works perfect! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You know that in VBScript, comments are written `' like this` , right?

Comment: Yeap. But that line was in the source .txt where I get values from, not in my VBS script. Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Quick and Dirty:

```
  Dim sFSpec1 : sFSpec1    = "..\data\frs.txt"
  Dim sFSpec2 : sFSpec2    = "..\data\sec.txt"
  Dim dicRpl  : Set dicRpl = CreateObject( "Scripting.Dictionary" )
  Dim reCut   : Set reCut  = New RegExp
  reCut.Global  = True
  reCut.Pattern = "(@[^@]+@)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$"
  Dim sAll    : sAll       = goFS.OpenTextFile( sFSpec1 ).ReadAll
  WScript.Echo sAll
  WScript.Echo "---------------"
  Dim oMTS    : Set oMTS   = reCut.Execute( sAll )
  Dim oMT
  For Each oMT In oMTS
      dicRpl( oMT.SubMatches( 0 ) ) = oMT.SubMatches( 1 )
  Next
  sAll = goFS.OpenTextFile( sFSpec2 ).ReadAll
  WScript.Echo sAll
  WScript.Echo "---------------"
  Dim sKey
  For Each sKey In dicRpl.Keys
      sAll = Replace( sAll, sKey, dicRpl( sKey ) )
  Next
  WScript.Echo sAll
```

output:

```
@PickupFolder@=E:/SonicDataFiles/AR_INT/GPP_VE/IN
@Db1Url@=jdbc:sonic:sqlserver://CARASETMS:1433;databaseName=CRM

---------------
@Db1Url@=
@Db1Pwd@=

---------------
jdbc:sonic:sqlserver://CARASETMS:1433;databaseName=CRM=
@Db1Pwd@=
```

If that solves your problem in principle, we can nail down details.

ADDED:

As Jean-François Corbett surely is right, use the pattern

```
reCut.Pattern = "(@[^@]+@=)(.*?)\s*$"
```

and the final replacement

```
sAll = Replace( sAll, sKey, sKey & dicRpl( sKey ) )
```

This version assumes a strict `@x@=[y]` format in both files.

Comment: +1 So much more elegant than mine! I think the OP wants the output format to be like what I wrote at the bottom of my answer.